# Magento 2, Grouped product images

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

I want to add images to items in the grouped data table. My code is:

```
<td>
<?php $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_item, 'product_base_image')
                        ->constrainOnly(false)
                        ->keepAspectRatio(true)
                        ->keepFrame(false)->resize(50)->getUrl();?>
<img src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>">
</td>
```

I add this column next to simple product name in grouped table on file grouped.phtml  but instead of base image from simple product i get defalut placeholder image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_item = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(YOUR_PRODUCT_ID);

$product_image = $this->imagehelper->init($_item,'category_page_list')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(FALSE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(120,90)->getUrl();
```

Comment: Still the same problem. I also tried to take code from cart where  simple products has images on the left side  but it still doesn't work  and i get default magento image

Comment: you need load product in $_item before used above code.

Comment: I update my answer, you need to do that things.

Comment: Sorry but i'm a newbie  so in:
load(YOUR_PRODUCT_ID);  what should i put in ( ) ?

Comment: you need try put $_item->getId();

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, not working brother...!